# docutils/reStructuredText template features

Tags: documentation, markup, restructuredtext, docutils

How could I customize placeholders in my `.rst` file with actual values?

For example, I have `example.rst` file with following content:

```
Header
------------------------------------ 
${custom_text}
```

I want to replace `${custom_text}` property with the value `this is the value of custom property` by running following command:

```
rst2html example.rst -o example.html -Dcustom_text="this is the value of custom property"
```

Also I wonder whether it is possible to customize template using `.properties` file? For example, I would like to run `rst2html example.rst -o example.html -p example.properties` command using `example.properties` file with following content:

```
custom_text=this is the value of custom property
```

Is it possible? Does reStructuredText support template features at all?

**EDIT:** Please note that I want to customize template from command line or using conventional `.properties` file (can be used by Ant/Maven build management tool).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Substitution in reStructuredText files is performed using the [`replace`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replace) directive. For example:

```
I am using |RST|.

.. |RST| replace:: reStructuredText
```

will result in the text

> I am using reStructuredText.

You could use the [`include`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) directive to define a list of substitution templates in a separate file. For example, given the following two files:

*example.rst*:

```
Header
======

.. Include templates from external file (this is a comment).
.. include:: properties.rst

I can include text, like |my custom text|, from other files.
```

*properties.rst*

```
.. |my custom text| replace:: "example text"
```

will result in the document:

## Header

I can include text, like "example text", from other files.

Here I have used the command `rst2html.py example.rst` to generate the HTML output.

Comment: You gave great answer about templating feature of reStructuredText. I need to admit that I didn't know about templating capabilities of reStructuredText even though I supposed there should be some way. But still, I'm afraid that's not going to solve my problem - I want to customize template from command line or using conventional `.properties` file (can be used by Ant/Maven build management tool)

Comment: You are going to have to write these things yourself. Since rst2html.py does not have a `-p` or `-D` option you'll need some sort of wrapper script. The `-D` behaviour can be achieved by running your reStructuredText file through, for example, the C language preprocessor. I'll have a think about the properties file when I have a bit more time. However, you are wanting to use reStructuredText in a way that it isn't designed to be used, which may be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems that you're right - I should use another format.

Comment: Is there any way to use the replace directive for *multiline* replacements?  I cannot get it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to handle templating:

a) use the internal substitution mechanism:

template.txt::

```
 Header
 ======

 |custom text|
```

example.txt::

```
 .. |custom text| replace:: this is the value of custom property
```

convert with `rst2html example.txt -o example.html`.

This way you can handle inline text and images.

b) Write your own wrapper: a Python script that reads `template` and `properties`    files, does the replacements, and convert with one of the function in Docutils.core.